# Connect Crystal Reports to SQL Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, crystal-reports

We have a reporting application that has worked with SQL Server for many years.  We are migrating to a SQL Azure installation and need to connect the application to the DB.  Here is how we are currently doing so:

```
ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Database crDatabase;
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables crTables;
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable;

crConnectionInfo.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrystalServer"].ToString();
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrystalDatabase"].ToString();
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrystalLogin"].ToString();
            crConnectionInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CyrstalPass"].ToString();
```

And our config looks something like this:

```
<add key="CrystalServer" value="SERVERNAME.database.windows.net" />
<add key="CrystalDatabase" value="DATABASENAME" />
<add key="CrystalLogin" value="USERID@SERVERNAME" />
<add key="CyrstalPass" value="PASSWORD" />
```

This does not seem to work with Azure as we keep getting:

The table could not be found.

Any hints on how to setup our config correctly?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate, please check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083897/crystal-reports-connecting-to-azure-sql-database-the-table-x-could-not-be-found